# Merging two mercurcial repositories of the same project

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have an old mercurial repository for a project that has the changes before a certain date, and I have another repository for the same project with all the changes after that date.

I want to merge these two repositories so the history reflects that the first commit in the latter repository is the child of the last commit in the former repository.

Is this possible? Or do I just have to merge both heads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading here:
http://blog.experimentalworks.net/2009/03/merge-vs-rebase-a-deep-dive-into-the-mysteries-of-revision-control/
and here:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension

I looks like what I am wanting to accomplish can be done with a rebase, with some caveats.

I pull the changes from the newer repo into the older repo. This results in two heads since both repos only have the 'default' branch. In the older repo folder, I ran:

```
hg pull -f ../newer-repo
```

Then I have to use hg phases to make the pulled changes malleable. Normally, this is a bad idea, but since I know I am the only developer on this project, I can do this safely.

```
hg phase -f -d -r 15 16 ...
```

Finally, I can now rebase because the history pulled in from the newer repo begins with the same state as the last changelist in the old repo.

```
hg rebase -s 15 -d 14
```

I have a single history and no conflicts. 
This probably wont work for everyone, but in this narrow circumstance, this was exactly what was needed.